# Generic type parameter and monads in TypeScript

Tags: typescript, functional-programming, monads

I'm currently learning about [monads](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monad_(functional_programming)) - and trying to use TypeScript to understand them better.

I would like to do the following:

```
type Bind<M, A, B> = (ma: M<A>) => (a_mb: ((a: A) => M<B>)) => M<B>
type Unit<M, A> = (a: A) => M<A>
```

But I'm getting the following TypeScript errors:

```
error TS2315: Type 'M' is not generic.
type Bind<M, A, B> = (ma: M<A>) => (a_mb: ((a: A) => M<B>)) => M<B>
                          ~~~~

error TS2315: Type 'M' is not generic.
type Bind<M, A, B> = (ma: M<A>) => (a_mb: ((a: A) => M<B>)) => M<B>
                                                     ~~~~

error TS2315: Type 'M' is not generic.
type Bind<M, A, B> = (ma: M<A>) => (a_mb: ((a: A) => M<B>)) => M<B>
                                                               ~~~~

error TS2315: Type 'M' is not generic.
type Unit<M, A> = (a: A) => M<A>
                            ~~~~
```

Is there a way of specifying that the type parameter M should be generic? Or is there another sane way of doing this?

The idea is that I can later pass for example `Maybe` in place of M, where Maybe is a generic type:

```
type Maybe<T> = { kind: 'nothing' } | { kind: 'some', value: T }
```

Comment: TS doesn't support such higher-kinded types. There is a [workaround](https://github.com/gcanti/fp-ts) but it's quite complex and hard to work with, because the language is bent to the limits. In order to learn monads in a typed setting I'd rather use purescript.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, TypeScript does not directly support *higher kinded types* of the sort necessary to define `Bind` or `Unit`.  There is a longstanding open feature request at [microsoft/TypeScript#1213](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/1213) asking for this, and it is not clear when or if it will ever be implemented.

TypeScript currently lacks the ability to abstract over type functions.  (A type function acts on types the way a regular function acts on values; it takes some input type(s) and produces an output type.)  It can represent individual concrete type functions like `Array`, and you can define new individual concrete type functions like:

```
type Foo<T> = {x: T} // Foo is a type function
```

but you cannot talk *about* type functions in general (there's no `Foo` by itself to reference), nor can you pass around type functions to other higher order type functions.  Since your type parameter `M` needs to be an arbitrary type function for this to work, there's no way to do it directly.

---

Note that I said it does not *directly* support higher kinded types.  It is possible to emulate higher kinded types, but all the ways of doing so that I know of are clunky and need a lot of manual intervention and boilerplate code.  I don't know that I'd call it "insane", but I also wouldn't necessarily say it's "another sane way of doing this" either.

If you want to use an existing library, you could check out [fp-ts](https://gcanti.github.io/fp-ts/). Otherwise a sketch of an implementation could look like:

```
interface TypeFunction<T> { }
type TypeFunctionName = keyof TypeFunction<any>
type Apply<F extends TypeFunctionName, T> = TypeFunction<T>[F];
```

For each type function you want to talk about, you need to [merge](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-merging.html#merging-interfaces) an entry into `TypeFunction<T>`.  For example:

```
interface TypeFunction<T> {
  Array: Array<T>
}
```

and

```
interface TypeFunction<T> {
  Foo: Foo<T>
}
```

Once you do that you can change any use of `M<T>` to `Apply<M, T>` where `M` is now the key you gave to the type function in `TypeFunction<T>`.  So you can say `Apply<"Array", string>` and it will be `string[]`, or `Apply<"Foo", string>` and it will be `{x: string}`.

---

Given such a sketch, we can write `Bind` and `Unit` like

```
type Bind<M extends TypeFunctionName> =
  <A>(ma: Apply<M, A>) => <B>(a_mb: ((a: A) => Apply<M, B>)) => Apply<M, B>;
type Unit<M extends TypeFunctionName> =
  <A>(a: A) => Apply<M, A>;
```

(note how the scope of `A` and `B` have changed... you want a single `Bind<"Array">` to work for all `A` and `B`) and even define other operations like [fmap](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Functor_(functional_programming)):

```
const fmap = <M extends TypeFunctionName>(
  bind: Bind<M>, unit: Unit<M>) => <A, B>(f: (a: A) => B) =>
    (ma: Apply<M, A>) => bind(ma)(a => unit(f(a)))
```

And just for fun we can implement `bind` and `unit` for the `Array` and `Foo` monads:

```
namespace ArrayMonad {
  const bind: Bind<"Array"> = ma => mf => ma.flatMap(mf);
  const unit: Unit<"Array"> = a => [a];

  const map = fmap(bind, unit);
  const mapYell = map((x: number) => x + "!");
  const strs = mapYell([1, 2, 3]);
  console.log(strs) // ["1!", "2!", "3!"]
}

namespace FooMonad {
  const bind: Bind<"Foo"> = ma => mf => mf(ma.x);
  const unit: Unit<"Foo"> = a => ({ x: a });

  const map = fmap(bind, unit);
  const mapYell = map((x: number) => x + "!");
  const fooStr = mapYell({ x: 1 });
  console.log(fooStr) // {x: "1!"}
}
```

Looks good, more or less.  I'm not thrilled with having to write `Bind<"Foo">` instead of `Bind<Foo>`, but since there's no `Foo` to refer to, this is as close as you can currently get.

I'll leave implementing `Maybe` to you.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?target=7&jsx=0#code/FDCWDsBcFMCcDMCGBjaACAKgTwA7QGICu4ykoA9uADwYB8aA3mgL7CS7rZ5ElmUByiALboAvGgDW0LOXiYOPUhWqJwWWmw5oAgjhwAbLFXxpoADxjgAJgGd53YkoHDoAGkz1xXAo77U6ANr4ALoA3CDseGgAQhBWVACyphbQ1nbein6CIp7AaGhU2rQAFEKIAFw6eoaJ7kUAlGii9FTRJYgA+kIARpXFxRU6jc1VBkYJ7m31w-S6Y7UxtOGR6ACq4KCQicmWtvY+vMrZ0Ln5he2V2jOjNRM6SyDIlDaQaPBlOE0FSea76Qq+I4uEp5NDdOKVWLWRK0dzETaVdabGHXQqTErwPqDK5NejRGag-KlbHVcZ1WjXcHWYn1Aa4tDwyDFeADab1EBgKBwJCofaZZQ0egMUHaWCwRBYS5iiWC4CsYDgFw2HAodCi8VYBKURBWRigp7gF5giExOJUABE6ol5s8aDK9KEchGZQAdPB9IhIAlEDhSvB6uF8gajYzERstpbpVgbV9EPSAogwiAg89Xh8vu8fcUqVY4eGA-rU3afQBNaD6fRfD79MyVcCEHpwa5mNAAajQ5oAhOaCynDa8XrA7OIPmWK8UAgBGdwAJncAGZgr20MHyPpoC79OQAObFQc2RoAekPaAC5sn3fc5pnl478+7wTlHJWaHw5HIgq+TFrmBYaGPr7vmgoB2HGL7wIClCcjACCqnykH+EKoJvuQlQobKrCKiIypwShWqKrqwp9kaOaQma5ooTGI5xs6Tr0I6xIumYy7Bq8oZoEiEaUbaNH0MU36VHGzAFoW-bFp84iZr6OZ5psLFFqO5aVtRvrFD+9aNrAzZth23byWJ8DvgAypAsBVqWSn8WgP6Tiw+k2GuG5bruhnkCZWn-ieDA-ue3asPKL7elg3TQJ+4hMBIJoAOTgOQkAABYQNuUV-gAPowkjRQ5IhRe4ABuiD6IQ0CVBgLDQdycEZAhn5EWgQUhZUDWhXQT7AEAA)

Comment: Very good example!